# Unable to produce multiply objects in javascript after eachother

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a simple version of flappy bird to help me learn JavaScript. I am using p5.js. I have made a constructor function for the walls that move across the screen, here is the code:

```
function Wall() {
    this.xw = width- 20;
    this.width = 20;
    this.len = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 50

    this.rects = function() {
        rect(this.xw,0,this.width,this.len);
        translate(0,height);
        rect(this.xw,0,this.width,-height + 70 + this.len);
    }
    this.update = function(){
        this .xw -= 1;
    }
}
```

I want these objects to move across the screen after eachother 
I used this code to attempt to do this. However my problem is that it is only producing one wall.

```
if(frameCount % 40 == 0) {
    walls.push(new Wall());
}

for(i = 0; i < walls.length; i++){
    walls[i].rects();
    walls[i].update();
}
```

I have also created an empty array and in the setup function I have written:

```
var walls = [];
walls.push(new Wall());
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have a console.logged the lenght of the array and it is increasing however the walls are not showing

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if you're still stuck here, I noticed something.

It looks like your function is fine, but you've got a little typo. An extra space is preventing `this.xw` from decrementing when the `update` method is called (`this .xw` instead of `this.xw`).

You can confirm in your console by typing `walls.length` and watching each wall get added to the array. But then they're all stacked on top (z-axis) of each other with the same position because each wall's `xw` attribute isn't changing.

For clarity, here's the change:

```
function Wall() {
    this.xw = width- 20;
    this.width = 20;
    this.len = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 50

    this.rects = function() {
        rect(this.xw,0,this.width,this.len);
        translate(0,height);
        rect(this.xw,0,this.width,-height + 70 + this.len);
    }
    this.update = function(){
        this.xw -= 1; // <-- this line here, remove the space
    }
}
```